# Flex-basis isn't working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flex items; `#left` should be 640px wide and `#right` should just fill in the remainder of the container, but if `#right` has really long words in it, it ignores `#left`'s `flex-basis:640px`, and basically turns it into some weird % width.  If I remove `#right`'s content, everything works as intended.

http://jsfiddle.net/f49nL0o7/

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I figured it out.  Since `flex-shrink` defaults to `1` for all flex items, I had to set that to `0` on `#left` so it doesn't mess with the width.

Comment: i was just 20 second to late :p